# Cannot get message row to delete from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to delete message rows from my database as part of a social networking site for a college project but am getting an error: Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: id in my view. Any help much appreciated!!!!

```
This is my method in the Model:

function delMessage($id)
  {

    $this->db->where(array('id' => $id));
    $this->db->delete('messages');

  }

This is my method in my Controller:

 function delMessage($id) {

    $this->messages->delMessage($id);

    redirect('message');

   }

And this is the code in my view:

 if(!empty($messages)){
           foreach($messages as $message):
           $delete = $message['id']; 
           var_dump($message); ?>
          <li><?=$message['from']?> says...: "<?=$message['message']?>"(<?=anchor("message/delMessage/$delete", 'delete')?>)</li>      
         <?php endforeach?> 
          <?php }else{ ?>

         <?php echo 'No Messages to View'; }?>
```

Comment: You're not providing enough info here. Where does the array $messages come from? Theres nothing about that either in your model or controller. What is the structure of $messages?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have this written you are calling the view without passing any data to it. If you're going to loop through an array in your view, you have to pass the array from your controller.

Your controller needs to look more like the following:

```
function delMessage($username) {
    $this->load->model('messages_model');
    $data['messages'] = $this->messages->deleteUserMessage($username);
    $this->load->view('message', $data);
}
```

In order for that to work, your model has to do more than just delete. It also has to query the database and return the array $messages.

I could try to help you more, but looking at your code I can't figure out what you're trying to do. You've assigned the variable $delete, but you never used it. You are dumping the array on each loop, and you're echoing 'from' each time. At this point, that's like Egyption heiroglyphics. Provide some more info please.

UPDATE BASED ON THE NEW INFORMATION PROVIDED:

```
function deleteUserMessage($username) {
    $this->db->where('from', $username);
    $this->db->or_where('to', $username); 
    $query = $this->db->get('messages');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $messages = $query->result_array();
        $this->db->where('from', $username);
        $this->db->or_where('to', $username); 
        $this->db->delete('messages');
        return $messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I kinda rushed into this...I have 4 fields in my "messages" table in my db - id, to, from and message. Gonna start over, what if I said something like this in my model.... function deleteUserMessage($username)
  {
  
   $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where('from', $username)->or_where('to', $username);
  
   $this->db->delete('messages');
  
  } ---> what would you suggest for the controller - sorry again - heads fried!!! :)

Comment: It's Christmas Eve, and I gotta go now. If you can wait until tomorrow, click on my username to get my email address and send me an email. Merry Christmas!

Comment: See my update above. Note that I modified to controller function as well. I changed the name of the model's function and loaded the model just in case you didn't already do that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The code above is deleting all messages from the messages table. I just want to delete one at a time. It also throws an error in my view "Message: Undefined variable: username" Should I be passing through "username"? Cheers!

Comment: I'm don't know why you would pass anything but the username. The code should be deleting any row that has that username in either the 'to' or 'from' column. If $username is undefined, I don't know how it could be deleting anything. When I run the code with an undefined value, nothing gets deleted.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. I tested the code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by deleting one at a time. If John left three messages, how do you specify which message you want to delete?